# Java Servlet 404 ошибка

Tags: java, maven, servlet, http-status-code-404

Пытаюсь запустить сервлет на tomcat 10.0 и получаю 404-ю ошибку, хотя вроде бы всё делаю правильно.

(tomcat установлен в `/opt/tomcat/`)

Порядок был такой:

- в `/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml` добавил виртуальный хост под локалхостом: servlet.loc

```
    <Host 
      name="servlet.loc"
      appBase="/var/www/tomcat/servlet.loc"
      unpackWARs="true"
      autoDeploy="true"
    />
```

- Создал в папке `/var/www/tomcat/servlet.loc` файл `ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` со следующим содержанием:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
      version="4.0">
    </web-app>
```

- Создал `/var/www/tomcat/servlet.loc/ROOT/index.html` с hello world
- Прописал в `/etc/hosts` строку `127.0.0.1 servlet.loc www.servlet.loc`
- Зашёл в браузере на `servlet.loc:8080` убедился что HW работает
- Создал файл `/var/www/tomcat/servlet.loc/subdir/index.html` с hello world
- Зашёл в браузере на `servlet.loc:8080/subdir` и так же убедился что HW работает
- Создал в InteliJ IDEA Maven-проект со следующим `pom.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>loc.vhosts</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <directory>/var/www/tomcat/servlet.loc/ROOT/WEB-INF/</directory>
        </build>
    </project>
```

- Создал класс `src/main/java/HelloServlet.java` со следующим содержанием:

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
            resp.getWriter().write("hello servlet response");
        }
    }
```

- Изменил `ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` на следующее содержание:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
      version="4.0">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

- Собрал проект с помощью maven и убедился что файл `ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/HelloServlet.class` создался
- Перезапустил tomcat командой `service tomcat restart` и проверил `servlet.loc:8080/hello`

**Тут я и получаю 404-ю ошибку от браузера**

---

**Что я пытался делать:**

- Перенес папку WEB-INF в корневую директорию виртуального хоста (/var/www/tomcat/servlet.loc) и удалил папку ROOT но это не сработало
- Пытался посмотреть логи ошибок но похоже я не смог найти где они могут записываться
- Переделал 10 раз всё заново по гайдам разного разлива из интернета, но всё равно получаю упрямо 404.

---

Прошу помочь, такое ощущение что не замечаю жирный косяк прямо под носом, но по идее всё должно работать! А так же подсказать где можно почитать про требования к файловой структуре сайтов на java и назначении xml-файлов внутри. Например, сколько должно быть папок WEB-INF? в каждой субдиректории или только в одной, какие должны быть конфиг-файлы, зачем и тд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак! Проблема решена. Излагаю последовательность действий.

- Я удалил tomcat 10.0 и установил tomcat 9.0.31
- Я понял на примере localhost что в директории хоста есть только одна папка ROOT, отвечающая за корень сайта и в ней может быть папка WEB-INF/classes, но! внутри субдиректорий не должно быть папок ROOT достаточно сразу localhost/subdir/WEB-INF/classes - в такой субдиректории я поместил скомпилированный сервлет HelloServlet.class и в папке WEB-INF я разместил файл web.xml с содержанием:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
      version="4.0">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Зайдя по ссылке localhost:8080/subdir/hello я убедился что сервлет работает, но! я почти уверен что на tomcat 10.0 такое уже давало ошибку 404, я не могу точно сказать что проблема именно в версии, но меня не покидает чувство что коренным образом поведение обусловлено неправильно выставленными настройками где-то в конфигах или переменных окружения.

- Затем я отказался от идеи разместить домашнюю папку за пределами /opt/tomcat, потому что похоже что у tomcat с этим проблемы, так же на уровне конфигурации. Поэтому домашняя папка хоста стала /opt/tomcat/servlet
- В server.xml я внес правки добавив виртуальный хост по образу и подобию localhost:

```
    <Host name="servlet.loc"  appBase="servlet" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve
            className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
            directory="logs" 
            prefix="servlet_access_log"
            suffix=".txt"
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"
        />
        <Context path="" reloadable="true" />
    </Host>
```

- Только я добавил ещё тег Context с атрибутом reloadable="true", эта настройка позволяет tomcat следить за изменением сервлетов без перезагрузки сервера.
- Так же я как и в прошлом случае добавил servlet.loc в свой /etc/hosts что бы можно было зайти из браузера
- Затем я скомпилировал в папку /opt/tomcat/servlet/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes сервлет с HelloWorld из моего вопроса и в папку WEB-INF положил так же из вопроса web.xml.
- После перезагрузки сервера всё заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь что это кому-то поможет в будущем. Спасибо всем, кто смотрел на этот вопрос и пытался прикинуть решение.

Если есть у кого идеи, что почитать по администрированию tomcat или в целом советы в направлении упреждения подобных проблем - пожалуйста дайте знать.

Comment: Отметьте как ответ.

Comment: Я пытался, но здесь есть ограничение, собственное решение можно сделать ответом только через сутки. Завтра обязательно отмечу, спасибо!